# How can I store value of array in a javascript dictionary?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I want to store array values in a js dictionary (for each date key, there is an array of objects for that date).
Is this possible? and if not, what is the best way to do so?
this is data (fetched from a json):

```
[
  {
    "date":"2015-02-08",
    "hour":6,
    "mac_address":"0C:3E:9F:60:53:32",
    "is_inside":"0"
  },
  {
    "date":"2015-02-08",
    "hour":6,
    "mac_address":"40:0E:85:52:68:4E",
    "is_inside":"0"
  },
  {
    "date":"2015-02-08",
    "hour":6,
    "mac_address":"60:F8:1D:DB:E4:A0",
    "is_inside":"0"
  }
]
```

I tried the following, but it just makes a long value of one string.

```
 for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
     usersByDay[data[i].date] += data[i];
    }
```

**What can I do to make a data structure like so:**

```
{date: [object, object, object], another_date: [object...]}, i.e:

{"2015-02-08": [
  {
   "date":"2015-02-08",
   "hour":6,
   "mac_address":"0C:3E:9F:60:53:32",
   "is_inside":"0" },
  {
    "date":"2015-02-08",
    "hour":6,
    "mac_address":"40:0E:85:52:68:4E",
    "is_inside":"0" }]
  }
```

Comment: Why is there a `+=` instead of just `=`?

Comment: Are you looking for `usersByDay[data[i].date].push(data[i])`? Can't tell. Learn the basics of arrays from a tutorial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: No I meant something different. I updated my question, hope it's clearer now. Thanks!